# How to use super class in another file in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a test class that inherits from a super test class.

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("some_fixture")
class TestSuper(object):
    def test_a(self):
        assert True

class TestSub(TestSuper):
    def test_b(self):
        assert True
```

this works fine if they are both in the same class.  When I move TestSuper to its own file and use

```
from testsuper import TestSuper
```

and then run py.test testsub.py, I get a NameError, name 'TestSuper' is not defined.

Is this not allowed in py.test or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the exact code in both files that raises the error as well as the error message you get? There may have been a typo somewhere.

Comment: I fixed the above code to run as a pytest.  I have the above code in two separate files (testsuper and testsub respectively) and i get the NameError: name 'TestSuper' is not defined.  If I move TestSuper class into testsub, I get a passed message.

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the exception you're getting. It should describe exactly where the error is happening, which will help us narrow down what's going wrong in your code.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a circular import problem.

Comment: Works for me... try using `import testsuper.TestSuper as TestSuper`

Comment: @Blckknght this all I get from py.test even when using the --tb=long options

_testsub.py:4: in <module>
    class TestSub(TestSuper):
E   NameError: name 'TestSuper' is not defined
=========================== 1 error in 0.02 seconds_

Comment: @JeD that does not work for me, I get _ImportError: No module named 'testsuper.TestSuper'; 'testsuper' is not a package_ if use testsuper.TestSuper

Comment: Are both files in the same directory? @dranobob

Comment: they are.  I have a single directory in ~/tests/ with both files and I'm running the py.test command from within that directory.

Comment: Can you show the `testsub.py` file, with both the `import` statement and the class declaration? I don't see how the import could succeed and the class give the error you're describing unless there's something else going on in between. (Please edit it into the question, don't put lots of code in a comment.)